# Path set error for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-8.1

After eclipse installation , its giving an error to set path for JRE : "No java virtual machine was found" .
I already had that installed in a different folder (java) ,so i copied JRE from "C:/Java" to Eclipse folder but now it is showing a different error : "Failed to load JNI Shared Library"
Please suggest me how to run eclipse.

Comment: You probably have a 32 bit Eclipse and 64 bit Java (or the other way round). You must have both 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Comment: i had a goof up while downloading jdk and installed 32 bit version.I'll download 64 bit version , hope it works. Thank You @greg-449